# Babies and blood. A innate knowledge?

Tags: toddler, behavior

Last night we were dining and my wife accidentally knocked over a bottle of wine. In trying to keep the bottle, the wine finished over her skin. Teresa (our 21 month old daughter) started suddenly to cry pointing at the wine on the arms of her mother.

It is really strange because apparently she wasn't scared from the tumble and she clearly confused the wine with blood. Moreover her experience with blood is really low: she has only bled a few times and we don't watch TV, only cartoons.

Is the fear of blood an innate knowledge?

Comment: She was probably just responding to the fall in general.

Comment: @balanced mama: I'm pretty sure no, she clearly pointed the _blood_ on the arms of my wife. Moreover the bottle not really fall down.

Comment: I have edited to try and make it a bit more readable.

Comment: Maybe she was just distraught to see good wine go to waste

Comment: I'm confused why the conclusion is that she's clearly afraid of blood because it was a red liquid. Is she familiar with blood in the first place? And why fear it?

Comment: Seems like an awfully big jump to say that a 21 month old saw a red liquid and automatically equates it with blood if they're unfamiliar with it? That's horrifying. She's watching Mommy drink blood.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim: probably as everyone said she just was scared by the events. In general I'm not  according with you: wine stays in a bottle or in a glass (maybe also on the table) but not on the arms, and what is in a bottle is something that you can drink. If something is on your arms, then   you cannot drink it.

Comment: @BartSilvestrum: (replying at your first comment) in general I think that there are many innate knowledge. For example a new-born is able to suckle or for example he is able to cry in the right circumstances. But now a new question arise naturally: why many poisonous plants are red coloured? Let me precise that I'm not saying that my daughter is scared by something that is red coloured.

Answer (score 6):

What you describe is not a fear of blood - in fact studies show any fear of blood is learned, not innate - but instead your baby will have picked up on a couple of things:

- Wine on the skin will look like a mess, and babies understand when something is different or messy or spilt
- You and your wife will have reacted to the fall. Whatever the response, your baby will have picked up on this. Pointing at the wine as one sign of the fall is quite reasonable.

Of the two, I think the 2nd is most likely. As @Beofett comments:

> ...kids that age are incredibly keen observers of their parents. They get most of their behavioral cues from watching how we react

Comment: Two things let me surprised: first of all the reaction; she was really scared, not like usually when objects fall down or something _different_ happen. Second she clearly pointed the wine on the arms of her mother, disinteresting of the bottle in front of her. She was really worried about her mother.

Comment: Could you show me where I can find this studies. they seem interesting. I known some people that have problem in seeing blood. Does this problem came from some not innate experiences?

Comment: Keep in mind that kids that age are incredibly keen observers of their parents. They get most of their behavioral cues from watching how we react. Generally, when adults spill something, our responses range from frustration to "oh, no! My clothes/computer/phone is ruined!".  In other words, we indirectly teach our children that spilling something can be Very Bad.

Comment: I think Beofett is on to something there. Spilling water certainly gets a much softer reaction from adults than red wine, because we understand that stains from red wine are much harder to remove than stains from plain water.

Comment: I will grab links for a couple of those studies. There are actually very few responses that are actually considered innate in babies. And some of them vanish after a few weeks.